# AngularJS - ng-options isn't working. Dont show up JSON response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I'm trying to show the values of a response JSON:

```
$http.get('index.php/administration/UsersAdminController/getAllDepartments')
    .then(function(response) {
        if(response.data.message == "success") {
            $scope.departments = response.data.data;
        }
    });
```

When i use ng-repeat the JSON shows like:

```
<div ng-repeat="values in departments">
    {{values}}
</div>
```

that shows me this:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Computación","description":"Departamento","positions":[
                                                                             {"id":1,"name":"Estudiante","description":"Yo soy un estudiante"},                  
                                                                             {"id":2,"name":"Profesor","description":"Educador"}]}
{"id":2,"name":"Quimica","description":"Departamento de quimica","positions":[
                                                                                    {"id":3,"name":"Quimico","description":"Soy un quimico"},
                                                                                    {"id":4,"name":"Farmaco","description":"Farmaco del dpto de quimica"}]}
```

What I need , for now, it is to show the names as options in a select.

I have tried in various ways, with ng-repeat and ng-options and have not been able to work. When i click on the select nothing happens.

```
<select ng-model="newDepartment" ng-options="key as value for (key , valu) in departments"></select>

<select ng-model="ciudadElegida" ng-options="departmet as department.name for department in departments"></select>
```

I think it's something in the ng-options value, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Pd: I have already implemented the script with

```
$('select').material_select();
```

EDIT: responding to Justin Herter

Thanks for the help! i use `$scope.departments = JSON.stringify(response.data.data);` then i show the content of departments `console.log($scope.departments)`

that shows me this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Computación","description":"Departamento","positions":[{"id":1,"name":"Estudiante","description":"Yo soy un estudiante"},{"id":2,"name":"Profesor","description":"Educador"}]},{"id":2,"name":"Quimica","description":"Departamento de quimica","positions":[{"id":3,"name":"Quimico","description":"Soy un quimico"},{"id":4,"name":"Farmaco","description":"Farmaco del dpto de quimica"}]}]
```

that is exactly what you asign to departments, so should be working, but is not. Again, when i click the select option nathing happens. im started to tinking seriusly about the fact that could be the materialize import that is making this problem.

EDIT 2: THE SOLUTION

The problem was all the time for incompatibilities between materialize and angular js.

Angular not allow modify an item after having instantiated. Materialize needs each time you update the select call his function `$('select').material_select();`

the solution was add a file with a directive so that every time the select is edited execute the function of materialize and the recompile of angular.

inside the `/js` folder save an .js script with the following content:

```
(function(e){var i;e.module("ui.materialize",["ui.materialize.ngModel","ui.materialize.collapsible","ui.materialize.toast","ui.materialize.sidenav","ui.materialize.material_select","ui.materialize.dropdown","ui.materialize.inputfield","ui.materialize.input_date","ui.materialize.tabs","ui.materialize.pagination","ui.materialize.pushpin","ui.materialize.scrollspy","ui.materialize.parallax","ui.materialize.modal","ui.materialize.tooltipped","ui.materialize.slider","ui.materialize.materialboxed","ui.materialize.scrollFire","ui.materialize.nouislider","ui.materialize.input_clock"]);e.module("ui.materialize.scrollFire",[]).directive("scrollFire",["$compile","$timeout",function(i,n){return{restrict:"A",scope:{offset:"@",scrollFire:"&"},link:function(i,n,a){var o=i.offset;if(!e.isDefined(i.offset)){o=0}o=Number(o)||0;var r=false;var l=t(function(){if(r){return}var e=window.pageYOffset+window.innerHeight;var t=n[0].getBoundingClientRect().top+window.pageYOffset;if(e>t+o){r=true;i.scrollFire({});s()}},100);function s(){$(window).off("scroll resize blur focus",l)}$(window).on("scroll resize blur focus",l);l();i.$on("$destroy",s)}}}]);function t(e,i){var t,n,a,o;var r=0;var l=function(){r=+new Date;t=null;o=e.apply(n,a);if(!t)n=a=null};var s=function(){var s=+new Date;var u=i-(s-r);n=this;a=arguments;if(u<=0||u>i){if(t){clearTimeout(t);t=null}r=s;o=e.apply(n,a);if(!t)n=a=null}else if(!t){t=setTimeout(l,u)}return o};s.cancel=function(){clearTimeout(t);r=0;t=n=a=null};return s}e.module("ui.materialize.ngModel",[]).directive("ngModel",["$timeout",function(e){return{restrict:"A",priority:-1,link:function(t,n,a){t.$watch(a.ngModel,function(t,a){e(function(){if(t instanceof Array&&a instanceof Array){if(t.length==a.length){return}}if(t){n.trigger("change")}else if(n.attr("placeholder")===i){if(!n.is(":focus"))n.trigger("blur")}})})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.slider",[]).directive("slider",["$timeout",function(i){return{restrict:"A",scope:{height:"=",transition:"=",interval:"=",indicators:"="},link:function(t,n,a){n.addClass("slider");i(function(){n.slider({height:e.isDefined(t.height)?t.height:400,transition:e.isDefined(t.transition)?t.transition:500,interval:e.isDefined(t.interval)?t.interval:6e3,indicators:e.isDefined(t.indicators)?t.indicators:true})})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.collapsible",[]).directive("collapsible",["$timeout",function(e){return{link:function(i,t,n){e(function(){t.collapsible()});if("watch"in n){i.$watch(function(){return t[0].innerHTML},function(i,n){if(i!==n){e(function(){t.collapsible()})}})}}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.parallax",[]).directive("parallax",["$timeout",function(e){return{link:function(i,t,n){e(function(){t.parallax()})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.toast",[]).constant("toastConfig",{duration:3e3}).directive("toast",["toastConfig",function(i){return{scope:{message:"@",duration:"@",callback:"&"},link:function(t,n,a){n.bind(a.toast,function(){var n=e.isDefined(t.message)?t.message:"";var o=e.isDefined(a.toastclass)?a.toastclass:"";Materialize.toast(n,t.duration?t.duration:i.duration,o,t.callback)})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.pushpin",[]).directive("pushpin",[function(){return{restrict:"AE",require:["?pushpinTop","?pushpinOffset","?pushpinBottom"],link:function(e,i,t){var n=t.pushpinTop||0;var a=t.pushpinOffset||0;var o=t.pushpinBottom||Infinity;setTimeout(function(){i.pushpin({top:n,offset:a,bottom:o})},0)}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.scrollspy",[]).directive("scrollspy",["$timeout",function(e){return{restrict:"A",link:function(i,t,n){t.addClass("scrollspy");e(function(){t.scrollSpy()})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.tabs",[]).directive("tabs",["$timeout",function(e){return{scope:{reload:"="},link:function(i,t,n){t.addClass("tabs");e(function(){t.tabs()});i.$watch("reload",function(e){if(e===true){t.tabs();i.reload=false}})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.sidenav",[]).directive("sidenav",[function(){return{scope:{menuwidth:"@",closeonclick:"@"},link:function(t,n,a){n.sideNav({menuWidth:e.isDefined(t.menuwidth)?parseInt(t.menuwidth,10):i,edge:a.sidenav?a.sidenav:"left",closeOnClick:e.isDefined(t.closeonclick)?t.closeonclick=="true":i})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.material_select",[]).directive("materialSelect",["$compile","$timeout",function(t,n){return{link:function(t,a,o){if(a.is("select")){function r(e,n){if(o.multiple){if(n!==i&&e!==i){if(n.length===e.length){return}}var r=a.siblings("ul.active");if(e!==i&&r.length){var l=r.children("li.active").length;if(l==e.length){return}}}else{if(e==a.val()){return}}a.siblings(".caret").remove();t.$evalAsync(function(){a.material_select(function(){if(!o.multiple){$("input.select-dropdown").trigger("close")}});var e=function(e){if(e.clientX>=e.target.clientWidth||e.clientY>=e.target.clientHeight){e.preventDefault()}};a.siblings("input.select-dropdown").on("mousedown",e)})}n(r);if(o.ngModel){if(o.ngModel&&!e.isDefined(t.$eval(o.ngModel))){var l=false;t.$watch(o.ngModel,function(i,n){if(!l&&e.isDefined(t.$eval(o.ngModel))){l=true;r()}else{r(i,n)}})}else{t.$watch(o.ngModel,r)}}if("watch"in o){t.$watch(function(){return a[0].innerHTML},function(e,i){if(e!==i){n(r)}})}}}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.dropdown",[]).directive("dropdown",["$timeout",function(t){return{scope:{inDuration:"@",outDuration:"@",constrainWidth:"@",hover:"@",alignment:"@",gutter:"@",belowOrigin:"@"},link:function(n,a,o){t(function(){a.dropdown({inDuration:e.isDefined(n.inDuration)?n.inDuration:i,outDuration:e.isDefined(n.outDuration)?n.outDuration:i,constrain_width:e.isDefined(n.constrainWidth)?n.constrainWidth:i,hover:e.isDefined(n.hover)?n.hover:i,alignment:e.isDefined(n.alignment)?n.alignment:i,gutter:e.isDefined(n.gutter)?n.gutter:i,belowOrigin:e.isDefined(n.belowOrigin)?n.belowOrigin:i})})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.inputfield",[]).directive("inputField",["$timeout",function(i){return{transclude:true,scope:{},link:function(t,n){i(function(){Materialize.updateTextFields();n.find("> > .materialize-textarea").each(function(){var e=$(this);e.addClass("materialize-textarea");e.trigger("autoresize");var n=e.attr("ng-model");if(n){t.$parent.$watch(n,function(t,n){if(t!==n){i(function(){e.trigger("autoresize")})}})}});n.find("> > .materialize-textarea, > > input").each(function(i,t){t=e.element(t);if(!t.siblings('span[class="character-counter"]').length){t.characterCounter()}})})},template:'<div ng-transclude class="input-field"></div>'}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.input_date",[]).directive("inputDate",["$compile","$timeout",function(t,n){var a=$("<style>#inputCreated_root {outline: none;}</style>");$("html > head").append(a);var o=function(){var e=/d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZ]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g,t=/\b(?:[PMCEA][SDP]T|(?:Pacific|Mountain|Central|Eastern|Atlantic) (?:Standard|Daylight|Prevailing) Time|(?:GMT|UTC)(?:[-+]\d{4})?)\b/g,n=/[^-+\dA-Z]/g,a=function(e,i){e=String(e);i=i||2;while(e.length<i){e="0"+e}return e};return function(r,l,s){var u=o;if(arguments.length===1&&Object.prototype.toString.call(r)=="[object String]"&&!/\d/.test(r)){l=r;r=i}r=r?new Date(r):new Date;if(isNaN(r))throw SyntaxError("invalid date");l=String(u.masks[l]||l||u.masks["default"]);if(l.slice(0,4)=="UTC:"){l=l.slice(4);s=true}var c=s?"getUTC":"get",d=r[c+"Date"](),f=r[c+"Day"](),m=r[c+"Month"](),p=r[c+"FullYear"](),g=r[c+"Hours"](),v=r[c+"Minutes"](),h=r[c+"Seconds"](),y=r[c+"Milliseconds"](),D=s?0:r.getTimezoneOffset(),b={d:d,dd:a(d),ddd:u.i18n.dayNames[f],dddd:u.i18n.dayNames[f+7],m:m+1,mm:a(m+1),mmm:u.i18n.monthNames[m],mmmm:u.i18n.monthNames[m+12],yy:String(p).slice(2),yyyy:p,h:g%12||12,hh:a(g%12||12),H:g,HH:a(g),M:v,MM:a(v),s:h,ss:a(h),l:a(y,3),L:a(y>99?Math.round(y/10):y),t:g<12?"a":"p",tt:g<12?"am":"pm",T:g<12?"A":"P",TT:g<12?"AM":"PM",Z:s?"UTC":(String(r).match(t)||[""]).pop().replace(n,""),o:(D>0?"-":"+")+a(Math.floor(Math.abs(D)/60)*100+Math.abs(D)%60,4),S:["th","st","nd","rd"][d%10>3?0:(d%100-d%10!=10)*d%10]};return l.replace(e,function(e){return e in b?b[e]:e.slice(1,e.length-1)})}}();o.masks={"default":"ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss",shortDate:"m/d/yy",mediumDate:"mmm d, yyyy",longDate:"mmmm d, yyyy",fullDate:"dddd, mmmm d, yyyy",shortTime:"h:MM TT",mediumTime:"h:MM:ss TT",longTime:"h:MM:ss TT Z",isoDate:"yyyy-mm-dd",isoTime:"HH:MM:ss",isoDateTime:"yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss",isoUtcDateTime:"UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'"};o.i18n={dayNames:["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],monthNames:["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]};Date.prototype.format=function(e,i){return o(this,e,i)};var r=function(e){if(Object.prototype.toString.call(e)==="[object Date]"){return!isNaN(e.getTime())}return false};return{require:"ngModel",scope:{container:"@",format:"@",formatSubmit:"@",monthsFull:"@",monthsShort:"@",weekdaysFull:"@",weekdaysShort:"@",weekdaysLetter:"@",firstDay:"=",disable:"=",today:"=",clear:"=",close:"=",selectYears:"=",onStart:"&",onRender:"&",onOpen:"&",onClose:"&",onSet:"&",onStop:"&",ngReadonly:"=?",max:"@",min:"@"},link:function(a,o,l,s){s.$formatters.unshift(function(i){if(i){var t=new Date(i);return e.isDefined(a.format)?t.format(a.format):t.format("d mmmm, yyyy")}return null});var u=e.isDefined(a.monthsFull)?a.$eval(a.monthsFull):i,c=e.isDefined(a.monthsShort)?a.$eval(a.monthsShort):i,d=e.isDefined(a.weekdaysFull)?a.$eval(a.weekdaysFull):i,f=e.isDefined(a.weekdaysShort)?a.$eval(a.weekdaysShort):i,m=e.isDefined(a.weekdaysLetter)?a.$eval(a.weekdaysLetter):i;t(o.contents())(a);if(!a.ngReadonly){n(function(){var t={container:a.container,format:e.isDefined(a.format)?a.format:i,formatSubmit:e.isDefined(a.formatSubmit)?a.formatSubmit:i,monthsFull:e.isDefined(u)?u:i,monthsShort:e.isDefined(c)?c:i,weekdaysFull:e.isDefined(d)?d:i,weekdaysShort:e.isDefined(f)?f:i,weekdaysLetter:e.isDefined(m)?m:i,firstDay:e.isDefined(a.firstDay)?a.firstDay:0,disable:e.isDefined(a.disable)?a.disable:i,today:e.isDefined(a.today)?a.today:i,clear:e.isDefined(a.clear)?a.clear:i,close:e.isDefined(a.close)?a.close:i,selectYears:e.isDefined(a.selectYears)?a.selectYears:i,onStart:e.isDefined(a.onStart)?function(){a.onStart()}:i,onRender:e.isDefined(a.onRender)?function(){a.onRender()}:i,onOpen:e.isDefined(a.onOpen)?function(){a.onOpen()}:i,onClose:e.isDefined(a.onClose)?function(){a.onClose()}:i,onSet:e.isDefined(a.onSet)?function(){a.onSet()}:i,onStop:e.isDefined(a.onStop)?function(){a.onStop()}:i};if(!a.container){delete t.container}var n=o.pickadate(t);var l=n.pickadate("picker");a.$watch("max",function(e){if(l){var i=new Date(e);l.set({max:r(i)?i:false})}});a.$watch("min",function(e){if(l){var i=new Date(e);l.set({min:r(i)?i:false})}});a.$watch("disable",function(i){if(l){var t=e.isDefined(i)&&e.isArray(i)?i:false;l.set({disable:t})}})})}}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.input_clock",[]).directive("inputClock",[function(){return{restrict:"A",scope:{"default":"@",fromnow:"=?",donetext:"@",autoclose:"=?",ampmclickable:"=?",darktheme:"=?",twelvehour:"=?",vibrate:"=?"},link:function(i,t){$(t).addClass("timepicker");if(!i.ngReadonly){t.clockpicker({"default":e.isDefined(i.default)?i.default:"",fromnow:e.isDefined(i.fromnow)?i.fromnow:0,donetext:e.isDefined(i.donetext)?i.donetext:"Done",autoclose:e.isDefined(i.autoclose)?i.autoclose:false,ampmclickable:e.isDefined(i.ampmclickable)?i.ampmclickable:false,darktheme:e.isDefined(i.darktheme)?i.darktheme:false,twelvehour:e.isDefined(i.twelvehour)?i.twelvehour:true,vibrate:e.isDefined(i.vibrate)?i.vibrate:true})}}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.pagination",[]).directive("pagination",["$sce",function(e){function i(e,i){e.List=[];e.Hide=false;e.page=parseInt(e.page)||1;e.total=parseInt(e.total)||0;e.dots=e.dots||"...";e.ulClass=e.ulClass||i.ulClass||"pagination";e.adjacent=parseInt(e.adjacent)||2;e.activeClass="active";e.disabledClass="disabled";e.scrollTop=e.$eval(i.scrollTop);e.hideIfEmpty=e.$eval(i.hideIfEmpty);e.showPrevNext=e.$eval(i.showPrevNext);e.useSimplePrevNext=e.$eval(i.useSimplePrevNext)}function t(e,i){if(e.page>i){e.page=i}if(e.page<=0){e.page=1}if(e.adjacent<=0){e.adjacent=2}if(i<=1){e.Hide=e.hideIfEmpty}}function n(e,i){i=i.valueOf();if(e.page==i){return}e.page=i;e.paginationAction({page:i});if(e.scrollTop){scrollTo(0,0)}}function a(i,t,a){var o=0;for(o=i;o<=t;o++){var r={value:e.trustAsHtml(o.toString()),liClass:a.page==o?a.activeClass:"waves-effect",action:function(){n(a,this.value)}};a.List.push(r)}}function o(i){i.List.push({value:e.trustAsHtml(i.dots)})}function r(e,i){a(1,2,e);if(i!=3){o(e)}}function l(i,t,a){if(!i.showPrevNext||t<1){return}var o,r,l;if(a==="prev"){o=i.page-1<=0;var s=i.page-1<=0?1:i.page-1;if(i.useSimplePrevNext){r={value:"<<",title:"First Page",page:1};l={value:"<",title:"Previous Page",page:s}}else{r={value:'<i class="material-icons">first_page</i>',title:"First Page",page:1};l={value:'<i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>',title:"Previous Page",page:s}}}else{o=i.page+1>t;var u=i.page+1>=t?t:i.page+1;if(i.useSimplePrevNext){r={value:">",title:"Next Page",page:u};l={value:">>",title:"Last Page",page:t}}else{r={value:'<i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i>',title:"Next Page",page:u};l={value:'<i class="material-icons">last_page</i>',title:"Last Page",page:t}}}var c=function(t,a){i.List.push({value:e.trustAsHtml(t.value),title:t.title,liClass:a?i.disabledClass:"",action:function(){if(!a){n(i,t.page)}}})};c(r,o);c(l,o)}function s(e,i,t){if(t!=e-2){o(i)}a(e-1,e,i)}function u(e,n){if(!e.pageSize||e.pageSize<0){return}i(e,n);var o,u=e.adjacent*2,c=Math.ceil(e.total/e.pageSize);t(e,c);l(e,c,"prev");if(c<5+u){o=1;a(o,c,e)}else{var d;if(e.page<=1+u){o=1;d=2+u+(e.adjacent-1);a(o,d,e);s(c,e,d)}else if(c-u>e.page&&e.page>u){o=e.page-e.adjacent;d=e.page+e.adjacent;r(e,o);a(o,d,e);s(c,e,d)}else{o=c-(1+u+(e.adjacent-1));d=c;r(e,o);a(o,d,e)}}l(e,c,"next")}return{restrict:"EA",scope:{page:"=",pageSize:"=",total:"=",dots:"@",hideIfEmpty:"@",adjacent:"@",scrollTop:"@",showPrevNext:"@",useSimplePrevNext:"@",paginationAction:"&",ulClass:"=?"},template:'<ul ng-hide="Hide" ng-class="ulClass"> '+"<li "+'ng-class="Item.liClass" '+'ng-click="Item.action()" '+'ng-repeat="Item in List"> '+"<a href> "+'<span ng-bind-html="Item.value"></span> '+"</a>"+"</ul>",link:function(e,i,t){e.$watchCollection("[page, total, pageSize]",function(){u(e,t)})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.modal",[]).directive("modal",["$compile","$timeout",function(t,n){return{scope:{dismissible:"=",opacity:"@",inDuration:"@",outDuration:"@",ready:"&?",complete:"&?",open:"=?",enableTabs:"@?"},link:function(a,o,r){n(function(){var n=$(r.href?r.href:"#"+r.target);t(o.contents())(a);var l=function(){e.isFunction(a.complete)&&a.$eval(a.complete());a.open=false;a.$apply()};var s=function(){e.isFunction(a.ready)&&a.$eval(a.ready());if(a.enableTabs){n.find("ul.tabs").tabs()}};var u={dismissible:e.isDefined(a.dismissible)?a.dismissible:i,opacity:e.isDefined(a.opacity)?a.opacity:i,in_duration:e.isDefined(a.inDuration)?a.inDuration:i,out_duration:e.isDefined(a.outDuration)?a.outDuration:i,ready:s,complete:l};o.leanModal(u);if(e.isDefined(r.open)&&n.length>0){a.$watch("open",function(i,t){if(!e.isDefined(i)){return}i===true?n.openModal(u):n.closeModal()})}})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.tooltipped",[]).directive("tooltipped",["$compile","$timeout",function(e,i){return{restrict:"EA",scope:true,link:function(t,n,a){n.addClass("tooltipped");e(n.contents())(t);i(function(){n.tooltip()});t.$on("$destroy",function(){n.tooltip("remove")})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.materialboxed",[]).directive("materialboxed",["$timeout",function(e){return{restrict:"A",link:function(i,t,n){e(function(){t.materialbox()})}}}]);e.module("ui.materialize.nouislider",[]).directive("nouislider",["$timeout",function(t){return{restrict:"A",scope:{ngModel:"=",min:"@",max:"@",step:"@?",connect:"@?",tooltips:"@?"},link:function(n,a,o){t(function(){noUiSlider.create(a[0],{start:n.ngModel||0,step:parseFloat(n.step||1),tooltips:e.isDefined(n.connect)?n.tooltips:i,connect:e.isDefined(n.connect)?n.connect:"lower",range:{min:parseFloat(n.min||0),max:parseFloat(n.max||100)},format:{to:function(e){return Math.round(e*100)/100},from:function(e){return Number(e)}}});a[0].noUiSlider.on("update",function(e,i){n.ngModel=parseInt(e[0],10);n.$apply()})})}}}])})(angular);
```

Comment: Can you do a `console.log()` and show us what is coming from `response.data.data;`? I think you should call `response.data`.

Comment: the console.log(response.data.data) show this: response.data.data: [object Object],[object Object] this two objects must be the two departments. The $result var work like this: $result['data'][$key]['name'] = $user->getName(); then:  json_encode($result); and that is what i get on the response.

Comment: test angular.fromJson(response.data.data) ->: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson

Comment: i don't understand for what is that

Comment: Do `$scope.departments = angular.fromJson(response.data.data);` and see what happens.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: It did not work. Shows me the data exactly like before. im not sure is the problem it is in that part... doing ng-repeat="values in departments">{{values}} i be able to see the json departments

Comment: Then, does `JSON.stringify` works?

Comment: I tried i does not work neiter. Someone told me that could be the materialize overwriting the ng-options of angular. any idea?

Comment: Not work, only helpme to see the string imprented on the console, sorry. The problem was solved for other ways, check the update.

Answer (score 0):

you should parse the JSON first:

```
$http.get('index.php/administration/UsersAdminController/getAllDepartments')
    .then(function(response) {
        if(response.data.message == "success") {
            $scope.departments = JSON.parse(response.data.data);
        }
    });
```

Use this to test your ng-options (taken from your example output above):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify([{"id":1,"name":"Computación","description":"Departamento","positions":[
                                                                             {"id":1,"name":"Estudiante","description":"Yo soy un estudiante"},                  
                                                                             {"id":2,"name":"Profesor","description":"Educador"}]},
{"id":2,"name":"Quimica","description":"Departamento de quimica","positions":[
                                                                                    {"id":3,"name":"Quimico","description":"Soy un quimico"},
                                                                                    {"id":4,"name":"Farmaco","description":"Farmaco del dpto de quimica"}]}]))
```

This tells me that your JSON object in response from server is malformed.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nd5x0z22/) is a working fiddle

Comment: I did it and i have this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. Pd: the response comes from an  json_encode($result);

Comment: try one level up JSON.parse(response.data).

Comment: Well the bottom line here is that your data is not a proper JS object and needs to be parsed, then your ng-options will work. Keep at it =)

Comment: need parse the response as a object?

Comment: yes, write a test object to test your ng-options in pure JS and then figure out what is wrong with your response data. I see something... using your output example above I was able to parse the JSON, see my edit.

Comment: i dont see what the problem is /: i use $scope.departments = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify... an that shows me exactly what i have before

Answer (score 0):

Since you solved your issue of the data coming from API wrong, now you have the problem of the items that are not shown in the view, so here we go:

First, you have some mistakes in your HTML, I corrected them and you can check below:

1. You don't put `value` name correctly:

   `<select ng-model="newDepartment" ng-options="key as value for (key , valu) in departments"></select>`

Also it should be: `key as value.name* instead of`key as value`;

2. `departmet` should be **department**:

   `<select ng-model="ciudadElegida" ng-options="departmet as department.name for department in departments"></select>`

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.departments = [  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Computación",
            "description":"Departamento",
            "positions":[  
               {  
                  "id":1,
                  "name":"Estudiante",
                  "description":"Yo soy un estudiante"
               },
               {  
                  "id":2,
                  "name":"Profesor",
                  "description":"Educador"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":2,
            "name":"Quimica",
            "description":"Departamento de quimica",
            "positions":[  
               {  
                  "id":3,
                  "name":"Quimico",
                  "description":"Soy un quimico"
               },
               {  
                  "id":4,
                  "name":"Farmaco",
                  "description":"Farmaco del dpto de quimica"
               }
            ]
         }
      ];
    });
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <span>ngOptions with (key, value): </span><select ng-model="newDepartment" ng-options="key as value.name for (key, value) in departments">
    <option value="">Select department</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <span>ngOptions without (key, value): </span><select ng-model="ciudadElegida" ng-options="department as department.name for department in departments">
    <option value="">Select department</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  ngRepeat of Departments: <div ng-repeat="values in departments" ng-bind="values.name"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: copy and paste errors xd ive solved the problem... was an incopatibility beetween materialize and angular.